# Is the configuration of a multi-region instance of Google Spanner customizable?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Is there any flexibility in where a multi-region configuration of Spanner's replicas are placed? Spanner's documentation indicates that the standard (only?) multi-region configuration consists of us-central1 (RW), europe-west1 (RO), and asia-east1 (RO)?

Answer (score 3):

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances#configs-multi-region

- there is no flexibility in replica placement, configurations are all pre-defined
- there are 4 multi-regional configurations offered at the moment

Two such configurations are offered in North America, one in Europe and there is one which spans several continents - North America, Europe and Asia.